# Should Questions be phrased in the personal sense?

Tags: discussion

I recently edited a question from "Will I ever be able to sing higher" to "Can Anyone learn to sing higher to make it more global, but then I started noticing this style of asking to be quite common.

*Should questions like this be re-phrased to something more global?*

Answer (score 3):

That specific wording in the question makes it "too localized". No one can give answer to if a specific persons ability to learn anything. And your re-write is not much better. The answer to that is simply "yes".

A better rewrite would be "How can I learn to sing higher" or "Which practicing techniques can I use to improve my upper singing register".

Note that the form is still personal, but no longer "too localized".

Comment: We may want to consider search engine optimization: when I do searches, I will do searches like "how do I XXX?", so having question content that matches likely approaches for formulating queries may be useful.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, the form "How do/can I XXX?" will be OK, but "Will I be able to do XXX?" is too localized, because that is directed to your special abilities, which will not be possible to answer..

Answer (score 3):

On the other side of the spectrum is searchability. I'd bet that a lot more people are searching "how can i sing higher" than "Can anyone learn to sing higher?".

If a question uses the word "I" in the title, it is not automatically 'too localized'. Part of the reason that that close reason went the way of the dodo was because it was heavily *abused*. The title "How can I learn to sing higher" can apply to more than one person. It depends on the context of the question, not how the title is phrased.